# Exporting from SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server database from a POS System. I need to export data to a new POS system. All I need is `Products`, `Prices` and `Barcodes`.

My problem is the barcodes are stored in a different table. I need to export multiple tables and merge them together if this is possible. I have no problem exporting each table and then importing but I am missing the barcodes as they are in a different table.

Can this be done with query builder or scripting?

Comment: are the tables located in different servers or databases ? what have you tried so far - code, tool etc. ?

Comment: Just wite a source query to join and shape your data anyway you want, what's the problem?

Comment: The tables are on different databases same server. I downloaded Navicat and Redgate. Just need t spend some time to learn each program. I dont know how to write a source query.

Comment: Show us the DDL for the tables and someone will sure help you do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write cross database queries by specifying 3 part names.

If you have a table in DB1 (dbo.Barcodes) as source and a table with the same structure in DB2 (dbo_NewBarcodes), the following query skeleton could be used:

```
INSERT INTO DB2.dbo.NewBarcodes (
    col1, col2, col3
)
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM DB1.dbo.Barcodes
```

If the structure of the two tables are different, construct your select query to transform the columns from the source table to match with the columns in the destination table.

Please note, that the order and count of the columns are important.

**EDIT**
If the source and destination databases are on different servers, you can either build the database on the source server, than create a backup and restore it on the destination server, or you can use cross server queries (see `OPENROWSET`, `OPENQUERY` and Linked Servers)

If there are some data in the destination table and there could be conflicts with the data in the source table, please check the `MERGE INTO` statement.

Comment: First link is the Blank dynamics rms 2.0 DDL  https://www.dropbox.com/s/3o1hhb3p90isdj1/rms.sql this is the other one https://www.dropbox.com/s/xvv6o5x0izitrgq/script.sql